# Filter data from list of dicts using condition in Jinja2 filter

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
data:
  - { name: foo, app: foo, isweb: true }
  - { name: bar, app: bar, isweb: true }
  - { name: foobar, app: foobar, isweb: false }
  - { name: baz, app: baz, isweb: false }
```

Desired result is list as:

```
{% set  list= [] %}
{% for item in data %}
{% if item.isweb == true %}
{{list.append(item.app)}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can this be implemented using filters :

```
{{ data | map(attribute='app') | list | join(' ') }}
```

Basically the question is how to implement the above for loop using a single line filter (as above) but only get data which have a value of `isweb` `true`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There can be several ways to do this (working with ansible 2.7. Not sure about lower versions):

**Pure Filter way(using `selectattr` and `map`):**

```
- set_fact: app_list="{{ data | selectattr("isweb", "equalto", true) | map(attribute='app') | list }}"
```

**Using ansible `loop` with condition in filter:**

```
- set_fact: app_list="{{ (app_list | default([])) + ([ item.app ] if (item.isweb == True) else []) }}"
  loop: "{{ data }}"
```

**Using Ansible `loop` with `when` statement:**

```
- set_fact: app_list="{{ (app_list | default([])) + [ item.app ] }}"
  loop: "{{ data }}"
  when: item.app is defined and item.app == true
```

Comment: Thank you for presenting all the variations.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're very close to solving it, just need to add another filter:

```
{{ data | selectattr('isweb', 'equalto', true) | map(attribute='app') | list | join(' ') }}
```